# Events do not bind to dynamically created elements till after that element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My events are not binding to dynamically created elements until that element has been clicked. So, the page loads, I can click the button and nothing happens, the second time I click the button it works.

Example code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#resultsTable").on("click", ".confirm", function(){
    $(this).confirm({
        text: "Are you sure you want to delete this entry?",
        title: "Confirmation Required",
        confirm: function(button) {
            //do nothing
        },
       cancel: function(button) {
            // nothing to do
        },
        confirmButton: "Yes I am",
        cancelButton: "No",
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn-default",
        });
    });
});
```

This is using jquery.confirm here: https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

If I just do:

```
  $("#resultsTable").on("click", ".confirm", function(){
      alert("Did Stuff");
  });
```

The alert pops up. What do I need to do for the first piece of code to get it to work on the first click?

Edit: Here is my template that I create the elements with:

```
  <script id="buttonsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="button" id="enterInPTPButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px; border-color:#3C5B75;">Entered In PTP</button>
          <button type="button" id="deleteEntryButton" class="btn btn-warning confirm" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px;">Delete Entry</button>
          <button type="button" id="offboardedButtons" class="btn btn-info" style="border-radius: 0; margin-left:10px; border-color:#3A7B8E;">Offboarded</button>
      </div>
  </script>
```

What do I need to do to attach the plugin to the `deleteEntryButton` each time I use the template?

Comment: It's a jQuery plugin, you attach it to the element the first time you click, so the second time you click it opens (and attaches it itself once more). attach the plugin wherever you're inserting the elements

Comment: Could you flesh that explanation out a bit more? "attach the plugin wherever you're inserting the elements" is cryptic to me.

Comment: Somewhere in your code your inserting `.confirm` elements, otherwise they wouldn't be added dynamically, and wherever you're adding the elements, initialize the `confirm()` plugin as well.

Comment: I'm adding the `.confirm` elements through JQuery templates. What would the appropriate syntax be to initialize the `confirm()` plugin there? I'm brand new to javascript and JQuery, and am definitely not familiar with what you mean by "plugin initialization". I have not encountered this verbage yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To be a little clearer, `$(this).confirm(options)` doesn't pop up a confirm dialog when executed, what it does is attach a plugin to the element, so the ***next*** time you click that element, a confirm dialog is opened. Also, as you're attaching the plugin to the same element you're clicking, you're basically attaching the plugin over and over, everytime you click that element, and you only have to call `$(element).confirm()` once.

Comment: WHY are you binding it in a click if you do not want that to happen? Assign it when the elements are created....

Comment: Ah, I understand what that does now. I did not fully understand how that worked. So, if I need to attach the plugin to the element when I am adding the element how do I do that? Do you have an example I could learn from? @epascarello because I do not know 100% how it works, which is why I am here asking for assistance from those of you more knowledgeable than me...

Comment: Added the relevant template that has the element that this plugin needs to be attached to.